# Why does the eager fetch on @OneToMany is not working even though I mention the fetch type?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a relational mapping between role and user, one role can be mapped to multiple user. Even though I mention it is as an eager fetch, findAll or findById is not fetching the target entity list.

**Roles.java (PK - id)**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "roles")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Set<User> users;
```

**User.java (has role_id column)**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Roles roles;
```

I tried both `findAll()` and `findById(long)`. The result log of **users** is always an empty array [].

Answer (score 1):

> @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) The association is going to be fetched lazily
> using a secondary select for each individual entity, collection, or
> join load. It’s equivalent to JPA FetchType.LAZY fetching strategy.

It seems like Hibernate considers `FetchMode` before `FetchType`. If you want to fetch eagerly, you can change to

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

or simply remove `@Fetch` from your association.
Refer to this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join)